# Resolving MultiIndex error regarding dtype being an object

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, google-sheets-api, gspread

When trying to upload a pivoted dataframe to google sheets using google drive api i'm being prompted with the following error:

### TypeError: Setting class 'pandas.core.indexes.multi.MultiIndex' dtype to anything other than object is not supported

Upon checking with dtypes i've seen that my index values were object and i have converted the columns values to oject as well but i'm still getting the error.

```
import gameData_connection
import pandas as pd
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from df2gspread import df2gspread as d2g

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials_files.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet_key = 'my_spreadsheet_key'
wks_name = 'My File Name'

connection = gameData_connection.getConnection()

print('Connect Succesful')

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql1 = This is my whole sql query

cursor.execute(sql1)
        df1 = pd.read_sql_query(sql1, connection)
        print('cursor.description:', cursor.description)
        print()

        for row in cursor:
            print(row)

finally:
    connection.close()



table1 = pd.pivot_table(df1, index = ["game", "platform"], 
                        values = ["new_users", "dau", "day1_retention", "day6_retention", "revenue", "arpdau", "arppu", "pau"],
                        columns = ["year_time", "month_time"])


d2g.upload(table1, spreadsheet_key, wks_name, credentials=credentials, row_names=True) 
print(table1)
```

```
Out[21]: 
time_join           int64
year_time           int64
month_time          int64
game               object
platform           object
new_users         float64
dau               float64
day1_retention    float64
day6_retention    float64
revenue           float64
arpdau            float64
arppu             float64
pau               float64
dtype: object
```

I can't figure it out what i'm doing wrong here. If i run `d2g.upload(df1, spreadsheet_key, wks_name, credentials=credentials, row_names=True)` instead it works so there must be a problem with something happening inside table1.

Please now that if write the same table1 to excel it works.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue using the df2gspread library implementation.  Providing my solution here since this question is not answered (and quite old!)

## The issue

The df2gspread library is written in a way the attempts to convert the columns and indices of a dataframe to strings.  Pandas does not support that conversion for MultiIndex types and generates the TypeError you see.  The [issue](https://github.com/maybelinot/df2gspread/issues/65) was posted in the repository here but not resolved.

## A solution

A solution is to instead use the [gspread_pandas library](https://gspread-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) that has an implementation that supports dataframes directly including MultiIndex rows and columns like in your example pivot_table.

## Solution applied to example provided

```
import gameData_connection
import pandas as pd
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from gspread_pandas import Spread # NEW LINE

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials_files.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet_key = 'my_spreadsheet_key'
wks_name = 'My File Name'

# NEW LINE
sh = Spread(spred=spreadsheet_key, creds=credentials)

connection = gameData_connection.getConnection()

print('Connect Successful')

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql1 = This is my whole sql query

cursor.execute(sql1)
        df1 = pd.read_sql_query(sql1, connection)
        print('cursor.description:', cursor.description)
        print()

        for row in cursor:
            print(row)

finally:
    connection.close()

table1 = pd.pivot_table(df1, index = ["game", "platform"], 
                        values = ["new_users", "dau", "day1_retention", "day6_retention", "revenue", "arpdau", "arppu", "pau"],
                        columns = ["year_time", "month_time"])

# NEW LINE
sh.df_to_sheets(df=table1, # Your dataframe
                sheet=wks_name,  # Target sheet name
                start='A1', # First cell to place the data in
                index=True, # Show the index
                headers=True, # Show the columns
                merge_headers=True, # Merge the cells of multiindex headers
                merge_index=True, # Merge the rows of the muliindex index
                freeze_headers=True, # Freeze the header rows
               )
```